# Установка разрешения изменения формы пользователем

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется форма, у которой свойство *FormBorderStyle = None*
Соответственно, это голое окно без всего. Каким способом можно "прикрепить" к ней возможность изменения размера? Объясняю, в обычном окне, со "стандартными" стилями окна, при наведении на края окна(углы) курсор меняет свой вид и позволяет растягивать форму и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Любой контрол, в том числе и форму, можно сделать с изменяемым мышью размером, перегрузив свойство:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        const int WS_SIZEBOX = 0x40000;
        var cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style |= WS_SIZEBOX;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Проверил: работает и с установленным `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, совсем не знал об этом свойстве, всё работает.

Answer (score 2):

Можно отслеживать положение курсора и нажатия кнопок мыши. Можно расположить по краям прозрачные элементы и отслеживать положение мыши и нажатия кнопок. Реализовать простейший Dran'n'Drop.

Comment: Думал об этом, но считал, что есть более изящные варианты